# How to use Android-Wheel into my project

Tags: android

I have zip file of Android-wheel but dont know how to use it into my project.What possible things can i do, Please suggest me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to unzip the zip file to some directory, and in your android project under build-path choose add external jar, and choose the jar in the unzipped directory.

Update: 
I checked Android-Wheel out and you will have to import the project from the google-code svn [Android Wheel](http://android-wheel.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/). In eclipse if you go to create a new project there should be a import from svn option. Once you do and the project is imported you can set it up as a library project and then use it in your app. To do that right click on your project, choose the android tab, and choose add under the libraries section.

Comment: i unzip the folder but didnt find jar file in it. Please tell me where is it located in folder.

Comment: This is assuming that you are using Eclipse of course. If you are not then just make a 'libs' dir in your project and put the jar file from the .zip in there.

Comment: yah i am using Eclipse but when i unzip the folder no Jar file is there, so how to create it.

Comment: Got my answer on right click to project go to export an there i find the jar option there :)

Answer (score 6):

I just made this tutorial, hope this helps those who use android wheel for the first time.

http://tolkianaa.blogspot.mx/2012/03/do-not-try-to-reinvent-wheel.html

Answer (score 3):

*Download project with Svn
*Import the project into Eclipse
* Once you import the project in the Eclipse, Right click on the project -> Properties -> Choose android tab and check the IsLibrary option
* Now Right click on your project -> Properties -> Choose android tab -> In the Library section add the imported project.